# SQLite. Stops at the first instance the WHERE condition is met

Tags: sqlite

I have tried this code and it works but only on the first instance for each customer. i.e the column should run through and add all the orders to the previous amount owing.

```
UPDATE customers_tbl 
    SET customer_amountowing = customer_amountowing + 
       (SELECT sorder_amount FROM standingorder_tbl 
           WHERE standingorder_tbl.sorder_customer = customers_tbl.customer_address1) 
    WHERE EXISTS 
        ( SELECT * FROM standingorder_tbl
           WHERE standingorder_tbl.sorder_customer = customers_tbl.customer_address1 );
```

Can anyone tell me whaere I am going wrong here. Cheers guys!!

Comment: what data is returned if you run a SELECT with the same `WHERE EXISTS` clauses?

Comment: Also, please explain your schema. Why is `customer_address1` seemingly serving as the primary-key instead of a `customerId` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the sum product of all previous orders, you should then use the SUM function in your subquery in the following way:

```
UPDATE customers_tbl 
    SET customer_amountowing = customer_amountowing + 
       (SELECT SUM(sorder_amount) FROM standingorder_tbl 
           WHERE standingorder_tbl.sorder_customer = customers_tbl.customer_address1) 
    WHERE EXISTS 
        ( SELECT * FROM standingorder_tbl
           WHERE standingorder_tbl.sorder_customer = customers_tbl.customer_address1 );
```

Comment: Thats excellent thanks. Problem is its working in the SQLIte manager tool but when I try to implement it in my android project using raw query it is not working. There is no crash but the data is just not updated when I refresh the SQLIte manager. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah. Dont worry about, forgot Cursor.moveToFirst(). All sorted. Thanks @uri2x